# Replace all special characters

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<a href=\"test\" />
```

I want to to replace the `/"` to `"`, so that it looks like this `<a href="test" />`.

Therefore I am using this piece of code:

```
content = content.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
```

For some reason it doesn't find `\"`. So it isn't being replaced.

Comment: Did you mean `<a href=\"test\" />` ?

Comment: Your string has `/` and you searching for ` \ ` ?

Comment: sorry my bad mistake no i need to replace the \" to only "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code: `string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\\""), "\"");`

Comment: Pattern.quote("\\"") is invalid because than i miss a "

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` takes a regex. Therefore, you must escape the escape like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"");
```

Comment: Thanks, that works also for me but i already accepted another answer that also worked